# Rejecting a promise throws "Uncaught (in promise)"

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, zone.js

I'm using promises to handle to handle a modal dialog: resolved when the user press the OK button, rejected when cancelled or closed.

To resolve and dismiss the modal I use this methods:

```
    let modalResolve, modalReject;
    modal.promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        modalResolve = resolve;
        modalReject = reject;
    });
    modal.close = (result) => {
        if (modal.isOpen) {
            modalResolve(result);
        }
    };
    modal.dismiss = (reason) => {
        if (modal.isOpen) {
            modalReject(reason);
        }
    };
    modal.promise.finally(() => modalElement.remove());
```

And when cancel button fires this method within the modal:

```
modal.dismiss('close')
```

Everything is working fine and the modal hides, but a console error is logged with this description and stack:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): close
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

It is weird because the modal is dismissed anyway, and this error is not shown on all modals I use, just in some of them. Resolving does not produce this kind error.

Comment: here's the smallest reproduction of the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/zonejs-promise-reject

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to `catch` it to prevent the error

```
modal.promise.then(hideFn, hideFn).catch((res) => {});
```

Comment: Is not .catch(onRejected) supposed to be the same as calling .then(onFulfilled, onRejected) with the second parameter being the .catch() handler?

Comment: yes you can do it that way, but base on the error the promise `throws` an exception that is why we have to call the catch to prevent the exception error.

Comment: There is not exception thrown, just a call to reject('close')

Comment: example would be this way `var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw 'Uh-oh!';
});` that is why the app crashed because of the throw, to prevent it we have to call `catch`

Comment: Doing `modal.promise.finally(() => {
          debugger;
        }).catch(() => {
            debugger;
        });` shows the same error after the `finally()` callback but before the `catch()` block

Answer (score 1):

just like Amaya said, you must use `catch` to catch the error, otherwise it will become a `UnhandledPromiseRejection`, different `promise` vender have different implementations to handle such kind of `UnhandledPromiseRejection`, but in either way, it will just be thrown at some point, so `zone.js` will throw the error in the next `tick`.

And I see you have already used finally, if you use finally `UnhandledPromiseRejection` should not be thrown, but you need to use `zone.js 0.8.26` to support `Promise.finally`, if the error still exists when you upgrade the `zone.js`, please tell me or fire an issue in `zone.js` repository, https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues

Comment: Thank you, I found that the cause of my error was that I was using `.then()` in other places of my code, without a `.catch()`. I thought that with one `catch` for each promise was enough, but it seems it has to be set for each listener

Comment: Javier Marín - Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, Javier Martin. I had the same issue. fixed by using .catch()

Comment: @JavierMarín please add  `.catch()` as a solution,add proper explanation and accept it as answer,we all facing same issue , Thanks